# Why is SockJS incompatible?

Tags: spring, websocket, jackson, stomp, sockjs

My app works fine when sockjs is using the websocket protocol. But I am getting an error in the server:

```
Uncaught Error: Incompatibile SockJS! Main site uses: "1.3.0", the iframe: "1.0.0".
```

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by manually hardcoding the SockJS version on the server side (Spring/Java) by

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) 
{
   registry.addEndpoint("/socket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS()
     .setClientLibraryUrl( "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sockjs-client@1.3.0/dist/sockjs.min.js" ); //Added
}
```

[jsDelivr – Open Source CDN](https://www.jsdelivr.com)